# In Bootstrap, what is the correct way to add a badge to a navbar image?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a Bootstrap Navbar that is fairly basic and populated with image links over text. However, I'd like to also include a badge - IE, show the number of messages.

[image: Image with Badge]

The problem is the badge position. It gets placed to the right, but I would prefer to justify it to the top-right relative to the image. It also directly affects the width and height of the link itself.

```
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <?= $this->Html->image('MessageIcon.png'); ?> 
            <span class="badge">42</span>
        </a>
    </li>
```

I have tried a few solutions that turned out to be fairly messy - forcibly setting the badge position, but ultimately they did not work too well. Does anyone have suggestions on how to handle badge position and link design in this case?

EDIT: To clarify, this is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Checkout this snippet**

```css
.icon.container a>img {
  width: 40px;
}

.icon.container {
  display: inline-block;
}

.badge-notify{
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
    left: -18px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul>
  <li class="icon container">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios7-active-2/512/Envelope.png">
       <span class="badge badge-notify">3</span>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="icon container">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios7-active-2/512/Envelope.png">
      <span class="badge badge-notify">3</span>
    </a>
  </li>
<ul>
```

Comment: Wrong position - I'd like to get it set to the top right of the image, not the default. This can be achieved by the native badge design

Comment: @Merlin you can use position relative check the updated code

Comment: Is there any way to safely include the span as part of the link, or is that not recommended?

Comment: @Merlin Yes, you can add span as a part of anchor tag. its absolutely fine.

Comment: Thank you for the attempts - they all ran into the same problems I was facing prior, I got it working in a reasonable facsimile again, and will leave it at this for now.

Comment: @Merlin Okay :)